# How to copy a mongodb document inside a collection using java driver framework

Tags: java, mongodb, copy, driver

as newcomer within the mongodb world I'm in trouble when I try to copy a mongo document inside a collection.
To copy I mean I wanna copy the old document into a new one with a new _id field as well as changing the value of a couple of fields.

The mongodb java driver is my operating context.

Does anybody already do that?

Comment: Do you want to update the existing document in the collection by adding some new fields or by changing values for existing fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the retrieved document's _id to a new ObjectId() and save. Sample in shell:

```
> db.sample.insert({"docName":"Old Document"});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> var doc = db.sample.findOne( {"docName":"Old Document"} );
> doc
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55ad11ea8306f3e7da87d62d"), "docName" : "Old Document" }
> doc._id = new ObjectId();
ObjectId("55ad122c8306f3e7da87d62e")
> db.sample.insert(doc);
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.sample.find().pretty();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55ad11ea8306f3e7da87d62d"), "docName" : "Old Document" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55ad122c8306f3e7da87d62e"), "docName" : "Old Document" }
```

Comment: Thanks so much CB,
I get the sequence from mongodb's console and perhaps to bring back it to a java procedure it could be resolved in a sequence sounding like:
find the document, change the _id (and something else) then insert. I Whished somenthing like a copy(from, to) API but nevermind I'm going to try.

Answer (score 0):

I just did what I called a copy of document:

just load into a cursor the docs to copy/clone or something then

`while (thecursor.hasNext()) {
    Document doc = thecursor.next();
    doc.put(Constants.ID, ObjectId.get().toString());
    collection.insertOne(doc);
    }`

It looks working!